# Copy certain values dependent on date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have 2 workbooks : `monthly.xlsm` and `annual.xlsm` . Starting with row 4 and column A, in `annual.xlsm` are the dates of the year. In `monthly.xlsm` are the dates of the current month starting with column E (the next date is in column G) . Now, if the date correspond , I want to copy from `monthly.xlsm` a cell from column with the date to the `annual.xlsm` corespondent row.

Ex:

`monthly.xlsm` has in E1 the date 27.01.2016, in cell E4 is the value Mike. In `annual.xlsm`, in A8 the date 27.01.2016. If that is true, copy E4 from `monthly.xlsm` to DR8 in `annual.xlsm`.

`monthly.xlsm` has in G1 the date 28.01.2016, in cell G4 is the value Mary. In `annual.xlsm`, in A9 the date 28.01.2016. If that is true, copy G4 from `monthly.xlsm` to DR9 in `annual.xlsm`.

I have tried with formulas but i can't figure a formula to leap the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In annual.xlsm, in cell DR8 put in the formula

`HLOOKUP(A8,Monthly.xlsm!$E$1:$G$4,4,FALSE)`.

Change the range and drag the formula